# Does this smooth function exist?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $f(x)$ be a smooth function satisfying $$f(0)=f(2)=0$$ and $$\int_0^2 (f(x))^2 dx=1$$ and $$\int_0^2 (f'(x))^2 dx=1$$
Does such an f exist? Why?
I'm (perhaps stupidly) presuming that this function doesn't exist but I can't intuitively think why, and I don't know how to go about the question mathematically. I know there must be a stationary point between 2 and 0 by definition. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would bet that such a function does exist. One possibility to construct it would be taking two free parameters $0<a<b<2$ and then setting 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x<0 \\ 
\frac{b}{a}x & 0\le x < a \\
b & a\le x \le 1 
\end{cases}$$
and then extend symmetrically along the axis $x=1$. (Visualize it, it is a trapezoid). You have two free parameters, so imposing your two conditions you will determine $f$ uniquely. Of course there is a problem: this is not smooth. But this is only a technical issue.

Comment: P.S.: If Norbert is right, which is most probable, then my previous comment is wrong. I am leaving it there though, perhaps it might be of some help. I wonder where the flaw is.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro the problem is that $f(0)=f(2)=0$

Comment: @Norbert: Yes, I think I understand what you mean. I treated $a$ and $b$ as if they were independent parameters, but they are not because of the condition $f(0)=f(2)=0$.

Comment: thanks- interesting, all the same :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such function does not exist. Use [Wirtinger's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions) 
$$
\pi^2\int_0^a|f(x)|^2dx\leq a^2\int_0^a |f'(x)|^2 dx
$$
to see this.